# WinSCP files editing and checking in windows

Tags: php, winscp

I am new to PHP. I am using WinSCP to check through a few already existing files. I need to make some changes in a single file. I have made the changes but not sure how to check if the changes are correct and the database tables are updated accordingly, before synchronizing the code.

Can some one please tell that how could I test the code?

I really need this.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

WinSCP does provide you with convenient means to edit a server file and re-save it to the server. (basically download > edit > upload).

WinSCP is not an IDE (Integrated Development Environment) like Eclipse or NetBeans.  So you can't test your code etc before saving it back to the server.

FWIW, I love WinSCP but not with it's own editor.  Pair WinSCP with Sublime Text 3 for a very powerful combination.  Takes some patience to get it set up the way you want it, but once you have the two working together it's a combination that is hard to beat (IMO.)